# What's the name for different navigation elements in a page?

Tags: interaction-design, navigation, design-patterns, terminology, information-architecture

We got into a debate about what to call the different areas of navigation, specifically what the definition of Secondary and Utility navigation is. And I was unable to find much on Google about standard navigation definitions. Take a look at these 3 examples and let me know what you'd call each number.

Also, note that these are not screenshots of a rollover state. This is of static navigation.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, there are often established naming conventions within a company that may not necessarily align to Nielsen's definition or other "standards" - so unless you are in a position to redefine how people talk about the various navigation structures, it's good to be flexible.

Both "secondary" and "utility" are open to interpretation (does secondary refer to "2nd level in hierarchy" or "less important than primary"? Must "utility" include tools? Can it include links to pages?). For this reason they're not great terms - the less ambiguous the better.

To your question, here's my response to the examples provided:

USAA

1. I don't really understand what these are, but maybe Global Navigation? Does selection of these change the main navigation below?
2. I wouldn't call this navigation - Search + Account Tools
3. Main navigation, primary categories
4. Main navigation, second-level categories

American Century

1. Main navigation, primary categories
2. Again, not navigation - Account Tools
3. You have a couple of elements here with different functions, so it's not really just one thing - I'd call the left-most item a Role-Selector, middle item Utility Links - right item Search tool
4. Main navigation, second-level categories

Charles Schwab

1. Main navigation, primary categories
2. again, multiple items - you have Tools, Account Access, Search - I'd recommend Utility Bar if you want to refer to the whole thing
3. Main navigation, second-level categories

Comment: Yeah, it is very true that often each company has their own vernacular, particularly in long established companies!

And I think you hit the nail on the head that "secondary" in particular is often open to interpretation. 

Thanks for your opinion on what you'd call the elements in the screen shots. Good food for thought!

Answer (score 3):

[**Utility Navigation definition**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/utility-navigation/) from Nielsen:

> Summary: Utility navigation consists of secondary actions and tools,
>   such as contact, subscribe, save, sign in, share, change view, print.
>   These activities strongly affect website visitor satisfaction, user
>   experience, and engagement. Put utilities where people expect and need
>   them.

[**Primary vs Secondary Navigation**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/planning-and-implementing-website-navigation/)

> **Primary navigation** stands for *the content that most users are
>   interested in*. But importance is relative; the type of content linked
>   from the primary navigation on one website may be the same kind linked
>   from the secondary navigation on another (for example, general
>   information about the company or person).
>
> **Secondary navigation** is for *content that is of secondary interest to
>   the user*. Any content that does not serve the primary goal of the
>   website but that users might still want would go here. For many blogs,
>   this would include links for “About us,” “Contribute,” “Advertise” and
>   so on. For other websites, the links might be for the client area, FAQ
>   or help page.

## More Resources

[**Other types of Navigation**](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/designing-web-navigation/9780596528102/ch04.html) *(Structural, Associative, Local, Contextual, etc)*

[**Antharia: Understanding Site Navigation: Key Terms (Part 1)**](http://dev.omeka.org/sbrennan/SearchTestO2/SearchTestO2/files/original/d583abc60d74cbbc48136977958bf10e.zip) (this is a zip file)

Comment: So what would you call the persistent navigation denoted with #4 on the USAA example and #4 on the American Century example?

Comment: those are not navigation, but full width sub-menus

Comment: Not to get too in to semantics, but why do you consider the #4s in the examples to not be navigation? Isn't a sub-menu navigation?

Comment: I think you're confusing things a bit. When we talk about navigation, we're talking of navigation areas, not every element that is inside a navigation area. These elements are what will define which kind of navigation area we're in, but they're not the navigation itself. It's very simple: if you click (or hover, don't know the behavior) over *Investing*, you'll see a set of links below. If you click *Investor Education*, you'll see another set of links. The navigation is still the same, yet the items INSIDE the navigation have changed. Reading theresources I added will help you understand

Comment: I would call it parent tab and sub tab for the global navigation. And the no 3 for AIC, no 2 for CS are header or utility navigation.

Comment: From reading the different articles and comments (along with my own internet searching), it appears there isn't common agreement on the definition of "secondary" navigation. Some would argue it's #3 in the ACI example and others would argue it's #4. 

I was hoping to find a more consistent answer for what to call areas #3 and #4, but that's not looking likely. We need a definition page to come to agreement on terminology!  ;-)

Comment: I don't know which resource did you read where a submenu is considered a secondary navigation, but I'm 100% positive none of those I posted. On those, terminology is really well explained, and a sub-menu is a sub-menu, and never a secondary navigation.

Comment: For secondary navigation,
The Anatharia article says "When referring to 'secondary' navigation, we mean the navigation that will be found under a specific primary section of your website. For example, a site with a primary navigation called About Us may have secondary navigation consisting of Organizational History, Board of Directors, Staff, and so on."

Comment: The Smashing article says "content that is of secondary interest to the user. Any content that does not serve the primary goal of the website but that users might still want would go here. For many blogs, this would include links for “About us,” “Contribute,” “Advertise” and so on. For other websites, the links might be for the client area, FAQ or help page."

Comment: So Smashing uses “Secondary” to indicate navigation that is not part of the most important links for visitors. And Antharia uses Primary/Secondary/Tertiary to define depth of “Main” navigation and “Utility” for the nav that Smashing calls "Secondary."

Comment: The definition of "primary" and "utility" seems to be the most agreed upon definitions. Everything else is a little wild-West. And then you throw in terms like subnav, metanav, and courtesy nav and then it all gets crazy!

Comment: Amanda: as long as you continue calling a sub-menu a navigation, you will NEVER find an agreement, simply because you insist in calling a sub-menu as navigation, WHICH IS NOT. Those articles are correct, the problem is your insistence in calling navigation to a sub-menu, I explained the difference above and really don't know how to explain it better

Comment: Devin, I'm not insistent on anything. I don't have a strong opinion on what something is called. I'm just trying to see if there's industry agreement on definition and usage of terminology, but it appears there isn't. I truly appreciate your research and commentary. :-)